# JProperty SelectToken when token has a period in it

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here is a section of my JSON

```
"facets": {
    "brand": {
      "Feit Electric": 175,
      "Halco Lighting": 28,
      "Satco": 6,
      "Mr Longarm": 3,
      "J&J Electronics": 2,
      "Texas Fluorescents": 2,
      "Dabmar Lighting": 1
    },
    "status": {
      "Active": 221
    },
    "bvc_product_type": {
      "Light Bulbs": 214,
      "Generic Product": 4,
      "Light Fixtures": 3
    },
    "product_type.lvl0": {
      "Lighting": 185,
      "Manufacturers": 19,
      "Closeout Specials": 9,
      "Lawn, Garden & Pool": 5
    }
  },
```

A portion of the code I'm using the retrieve the JSON is this...

```
if (res["facets"] != null)
            {
                instance.Refinables = new List<IRefinable>();
                foreach (JProperty item in res["facets"])
                {
                    Refinable refinable = new Refinable();
                    refinable.Values = new List<IRefinableValue>();
                    refinable.Name = item.Name;

                    foreach (JProperty prop in res["facets"].SelectToken(item.Name))
                    {
                        IRefinableValue refinableValue = new RefinableValue();
                        refinableValue.RefinableName = item.Name;
                        refinableValue.Name = prop.Name.ToString();
                        refinableValue.Count = Convert.ToInt32(prop.Value.ToString());

                        refinable.Values.Add(refinableValue);
                    }

                    instance.Refinables.Add(refinable);
                }
            }
```

The SelectToken(item.Name) works well except when the JSON returns a hierarchy of facets (.lvl0  .lvl1 etc...).

The error I get is this.

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any help on selecting the JProperty would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the name you're passing to the `SelectToken` method.

```
res["facets"].SelectToken($"['{item.Name}']")
```

Reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenEscaped.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Works great, and I appreciate the reference as well.